# How to set bean property name through spring boot config file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to set the bean property name through application configuration file. In the below use case there'll be always only one detail of the employee such as age, position etc.. Instead of adding bean properties for each detail, is there a simpler way to drive the property name through the configuration?

```
@Setter @Getter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "company")
public Company {
    List<Employee> employees;

    @Setter @Getter
    public Employee {
        String name;
        Details details;

        @Setter @Getter
        public Details {
            // Should the class have properties for each detail? 
            // or can the name be driven through config

            String age;
            String position;

            OR

            String <<placeholder>>;
        }
    }
}
```

```
application.yml
---------------
company:
  employee:
  - name: john
    details:
      age: 25
  - name: doe
    details:
      position: developer
```

Comment: Unless you are dynamically creating classes yourself this cannot be done (simply because it is a language restriction). You could shoehorn this into a regular `Map`. But then again, what are you going to do with those dynamic properties? How is the remainder of your code going to know what to use/work with it?

Comment: I Agree with you, the business processing will be difficult in case if I don't know the property name but here I just need to return the values from config. No further processing is required.

Comment: Then why make it more complex than a `Map` if you don't catre about anything else and it is free format.